# How can an Xpath be written for search results that change

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, codeception

I have a scenario where i am filling a search field with text 'A' and it returns a bunch of results. These results are always changing and i simply want to select the first 5 options. How is it possible to write an Xpath for this. I am trying to write an acceptance test using codecption

`.//*[@id='js_search_table_filter']` - is the search table filter. I enter A with this below

```
 $this->fillField($_sSelectSearchXPath,"A");
```

The xpath element when i click on the tick box option for the search results are like

```
.//*[@id='assign-9488'].



<label class="checkbox checked" for="assign-9488">
```

Note that the numbers vary and they are not in any chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but if you need the first 5 elements of a nodeset, you can suffix it with:

```
[position() <= 5]
```

Example:

```
<a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>2</c>
    <d>3</d>
    <e>4</e>
    <f>5</f>
    <g>6</g>
</a>
```

If you want to get elements from `b` to `f`, you can run `/a/*[position() <= 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how codeception/php version works but in ruby (watir or pageobjectgem) you can identify all elements with a reqular expression or a partial match

the element would look like:

```
checkboxes(:your_element_name, :id => /assign/)
```

Notice the difference between checkbox and checkboxes which returns all checkboxes which have id containing assign.

In Java Webdriver, you have

```
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//checkbox[contains(@id,'assign')]"));
```

Both representatinos (ruby and java) return an array of elements where the Java solution is using xpath. The element you mentioned is a label, if you are looking for the checkbox, it is possibly a child element of this label and the xpath will be

```
        //label[contains(@for,'assign')]/checkbox
```

Basically, you can use "contains" method in xpath to identify your element. You can then take the first five elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I used this guys and tried to select all the tickboxes in the dropdown
(.//*[@type='checkbox'])[1]